# Does anyone know a book on sketching surfaces?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, solid-geometry

Is anyone aware of books or sources dedicated to sketching surfaces? Sort of like Forst's An Elementary Treatise on Curve Tracing, but on surfaces; or a book that has a fair few chapters dedicated to this matter (it could be on anything - multivariable calculus, solid geometry etc).

I've found books on analytical geometry in three dimensions but there isn't much sketching there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A Topological Picturebook by Francis, George K.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387345426)